# Unrecognized mount option "uid=33" or missing value

Tags: mount

I'm trying to mount a partition with -o option, however I get this error

```
root@blackbox:~# mount /dev/sda1 /media/ownclouddrive -o uid=33,gid=33
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

[  365.432693] EXT4-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=33" or missing value
```

If I checl my /etc/passwd I can see the user there

```
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: ``uid`` and ``gid`` are options for filesystems that don’t support permissions, e. g. vfat. They’d make little sense for ext4.

Comment: And to override ownership for all files on a file-system (without actually modifying the file metadata stored on the filesystem), you could look at `bindfs`

Comment: So, the suggestion is to change the partition in NTFS?

Comment: A first suggestion would be to remove the `uid=33,gid=33` options to the `mount` command. If that's not acceptable please [edit] your question to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Federi In addition to what @roaima recommends, if you need all ``33:33`` permissions on that filesystem, then just ``chown -R`` its contents once after mounting.

Comment: @phg Thanks. That was the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 14):

You are getting that error message because you specify mount
options that don’t apply to the filesystem on the device.

The mount options `uid=` and `gid=` are not valid for all
available filesystems. The ones that support proper permissions
usually don’t accept them, as is the case for that ext4 device
you’re attempting to mount.

For filesystems with limited functionality like VFAT, the options
`uid` and `gid` allow mapping the ownership of the entire
contents of a mounted filesystem to a single local user. Similar
options exist for other properties like the umask.

Note that this is not the proper way to grant permissions to the
contents, but rather a workaround to integrate certain FS into a
unixoid environment. On an ext4 partition like the one you’re
attempting to mount, just change the ownership directly:

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /media/ownclouddrive
chown -R 33:33 /media/ownclouddrive/*
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks for this answer. It seems obvious, in hindsight, that changing the ownership directly is the right approach, but... I just caught myself trying to do the _exact same thing_ as the OP, i.e., manipulating permissions for an EXT4-formatted partition via the `uid=` option in `/etc/fstab`. Glad my Google search for `Unrecognized mount option "uid=` led me to this answer!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to phg, you can use option `user` i.e.

```
mount /dev/sda1 /media/ownclouddrive -o user=www-data,rw
```